# Entity Framework many-to-many navigation without junction entity

Tags: entity-framework

With the following table structure.

[image]

How can I create a navigation property for Sprockets, filtered by CompanyId, in my Widget class without having to add and use a navigation property for Sprockets in the Company entity.

```
class Widget {
   public int CompanyId {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Sprocket> Sprockets {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I beileve the answer is, no, at least not yet.  "Skip collections" were added in EF Core 5, but currently they only support Many-to-Many relationships where the linking entity is on the many side of both relationships.  See https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21673

Of course you add a NotMapped property, you just can't use it in LINQ-to-Entities.

```
public class Widget
{
    public int WidgetId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public  ICollection<Sprocket> Sprockets 
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.Company.Sprockets;
        }
    } 

}
```